# What does IsNull in SQL Server procedure do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following update statement already written in a SQL Server stored procedure.

What does `IsNull` do here?

```
Update [dbo].[Images]
set ImageName = IsNull(@ImageName, ImageName), ItemId = IsNull(@ItemId, ItemId)  
where TypeId = @TypeId;
```

I am fairly new to database stuff.

Comment: just google `ISNULL()`

Comment: `If @ImageName IS NOT NULL then @ImageName else ImageName `

Comment: So it does not replaces the value when null parameter is passed?

Comment: @Noob it replaces it with its original value which is logically a no-op.

Comment: correct.. it will actually set the value equal to itself

Comment: Actually this could have an (undesired) effect if the parameter datatypes are different from that of the columns. Because it will cast the column value to the parameter datatype and so you could potentially end up with truncation or other bugs.

Comment: I see  -3 on my question, that mean downvote ?

Comment: @Noob yes, it does

Comment: Oh yeah , Noob is getting noob treatment !

Comment: @Noob more than "noob treatment" (whatever that is), this question showed zero effort. A single search on google would've answered your doubts

Comment: @Noob - It is because had you simply Google'd the text in your title, you would get the answer to your question. It makes it appear as though you did not try to find the answer on your own.

Comment: I tried finding out the answer but was not sure whether the value in table will remain unchanged as another variable (the second one) was never defined. And it had column name which puzzled me a bit ! No worries , what we throw comes back to us ! I did throw smaller stone, and it must fall on my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to `COALESCE` in that it returns the value of the second parameter if the first is `NULL`.

You have to be careful with `ISNULL` in certain situations because it may truncate the second parameter value if the type of the first is defined as smaller. For instance:

```
DECLARE @val1 CHAR(1);
DECLARE @val2 CHAR(2) = 'AB';

SELECT ISNULL(@val1,@val2); -- Returns 'A', not 'AB'
SELECT COALESCE(@val1,@val2); -- Returns 'AB'
```